# Two tables right beside each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want `#idTable` and `#userTable` to be beside each other and the button below `#idTable`. I have tried `display: inline-block;` but it didn't help. Also, I have tried to put the button after the `div#userTable` but that would make the button go down more every time that table gets populated with more data. I want the button to remain still on the left side. While the `#userTable` and its info on the right side of the first table.

HTML:

```
<input type="date" />
<input type="date" />
<br style="clear:both" />
<table border="1" id="idTable">
    <tr>
        <th><b>#</b>

        </th>
        <th><b>ID</b>

        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>// #'s here</td>
        <td>// ID's here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br style="clear:both" />
<button>Update</button>
<div id="userTable">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><b>ID</b>

            </td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table border="1" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>ID</b></td>
                        <td><b>Name</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#idTable{
    display:inline-block;
}

#userTable{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/82zv67d7/)

Comment: what are you adding clear for?  you have not floated anything. anyways, add button as display block. http://jsfiddle.net/82zv67d7/2/ and many ways this can be achieved, this is one way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/82zv67d7/4/ @radiant this is the problem

Comment: unless there are elements floating, clear floating will be unnecessary in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `#idTable` and the button into another `div` (e.g. `#wrapper`) and set its [`float` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) to `left`.

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <table border="1" id="idTable">
        <tr>
            <th><b>#</b>

            </th>
            <th><b>ID</b>

            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>// #'s here</td>
            <td>// ID's here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button>Update</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    float: left;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/82zv67d7/7

Comment: jsfiddle.net/82zv67d7/4 @vaultah this is the problem. I want the button to remain position right under the first table. Not move as the second table gets bigger

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/82zv67d7/5/ , wrap the first table and button in a div and float the div to the left;